# Performing mathematical operations in Xcode using Text Fields?

Tags: xcode4.2

I want to use the values entered in the text Fields by the users in two columns and perform the necessary operations to generate the desired output and display the result as an alert message in XCODE?
Is there any way that i can perform the calculations using the text fields ?

got the ans:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
{
    // You may also need to check if your string data is a valid number
    int result = [Number1.text intValue] + [Number2.text intValue];
    SumAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This above code is correct. This will show result in third textbox.
If you want to show result in `UIAlertView`

Try 
[UIAlertView](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIAlertView.html)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result !!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result]; delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // optional - add more buttons:
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert show];
```

And don't forget to add `UIAlertViewDelegate` in .h class

Comment: but how to display the text value(sumAnswer.text) in the alert box ?

Comment: you don't need to display textfield in that alert.... You can directly show result in that alert.

Comment: how to display an text in an alert box?

Comment: @SivabalanBalasubramanian that is what the above code explains.. just try to understand the above code